# vb.net display date field without time

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am new to vb.net so apologies in advance if im asking a glaringly obvious one.

I have declared the following code in my pageload, it displays todays date in a label however it was displaying the date and time.

It originally said DateTime but I changed it to just Date in the hope this would work but it continued to display the time also.

I have used the left operator for now to trim it down to 10 characters however I would like to know what I should have done if id only wanted the date and not the time without having to trim the results.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


    Dim dtNow As Date = Date.Now
    time_stamp_entryLabel1.Text = Left(dtNow.ToString, 10)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Code**

```
Dim d As DateTime = Now
d.ToLongDateString
d.ToShortDateString
d.ToString("d")
d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

**Results**

```
Wednesday, December 10, 2008
12/10/2008
12/10/2008
2008-12-10
```

**[Further Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)**

Comment: Most of those results will vary depending on culture.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it in aspx

```
<asp:Label ID="DateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Format(Date.ParseExact("09/09/1955", "d", New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"))) %>' />
```